# Python: Set number of clusters for HDBSCAN

Tags: python, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I am using HDBSCAN for outlier detection. I already know how many clusters the algorithm should use. How do I set the number of clusters?

Maybe with fcluster of the scipy.cluster.hierarchy library?

Found this post: [HDBSCAN Python choose number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269092/hdbscan-python-choose-number-of-clusters)

but do ot know how to use labels afterwards. Can anyone give an example for fclusters or has another idea to set numbers of clusters for hdbscan?

Thank you,
MaMo

Comment: If you already know the number of clusters you need why don't you use other algorithm like Gaussian Mixture model in which you can easily set the number of clusters? in HDBSCAN you can set min cluster size and based on the data structure it will return the number of clusters needed for structuring your data.